# systemd path unit files - how do I get the filename that triggered the path unit file

Tags: bash, systemd

I want to use systemd path unit files to run a script when a file gets copied into a particular folder.  Where I'm failing is that I don't know how to get the filename that triggered the systemd path unit into the script that I want to run.

Does anyone know how I can use the filename that triggered the systemd event in the bash script that I want to run?

[Red Hat introduction to path units](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/introduction-path-units),

Comment: Look at the results of `env | sort` in th target script. Maybe the information is passed in environment variables.